# Flask form (with multiple looped radio buttons) post call - request.form is returning an empty response

Tags: python, html, flask

This is the code in my python file(app.py). I am requesting the form data from play.html, "li1" is empty.

```
@app.route('/play', methods = ['GET', 'POST']) #decorator defines the
@login_required   
def play():
    req = requests.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10')
    data = req.content
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    data = json_data['results']
    li1 = request.form.get('selected_')
    print(li1)
    return render_template('play.html',data = data);
```

This is my form in [[[my play.html file]](https://www.writeurl.com/text/wpjfemuch2k39etq1tgg/nfkuxxkem0lzvyl0b1er)] file.

The Form is like this:

There are 10 questions and options are given for each question (in form of radio buttons).

After clicking submit, I expect to get the user's response to each question(The option he/she clicked). But I am getting an empty response.

[Screenshot of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diYuU.png)

Comment: It seems that the link to your HTML file with the form is missing.
Also, you can use `req.json()` instead of `json.loads(req.content)`

Comment: Edit: I realized that my link to play.html was wrong, I edited it now, if you want to have look. Thanks

Comment: Your html page does not contain any form input with the name **selected_**

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. I found my mistake, I was calling 'selected_'  whereas each response was named as, 'selected_0', 'selected_1' ... and so on.